# Overhead of creating a new class

Tags: c++, class, optimization, int

If I have a class defined as such:

```
class classWithInt
{
public:
    classWithInt();
...
private:
    int someInt;
...
}
```

and that `someInt` is the one and only one member variable in `classWithInt`, how much slower would it be to declare a new instance of this class than to just declare a new integer?

What about when you have, say 10 such integers in the class? 100?

Comment: Classes are The Devil. You should never use them. All your code should be in a single, huge module with lots of functions, and should use simple types in global variables. On a related note; I should stop visiting this site when feeling especially sarcastic. :p

Comment: Why not try creating 100 classes and 100 ints? or even one million ints!

Comment: Have you tried it and profiled it? Why does it matter? Why would you do this? I'll bet it's hundreds of times slower, but your compiler MIGHT be able to do some fancy stuff. What use case do you have that makes this relevant?

Comment: The answer depends on whether or not your classWithInt() constructor computes pi and stores the millionth decimal place into someInt. :-)

Comment: @Andrew Barber: You forgot to also recommend the liberal use of `goto`s in lieu of `else` and the various structured looping constructs such as `for` and `while`.

Comment: In compiled object-oriented languages like C++, class declarations only slow down compilation -- and probably not enough for you to ever notice or even be able measure. At runtime it will vary a little more depending on instance size, the number of base classes, and what the constructor does. Primate types like `int`, which isn't a class are very light-weight and both compile and runtime because the semantics are built-in and close to what the hardware naturally does.

Comment: @martineau : I am shamed by your thoroughness in completing my lacking answer! :p

Answer (score 56, accepted):

With a compiler not written by drunk college students in the wee hours of the morning, the overhead is zero. At least until you start putting in `virtual` functions; then you must pay the cost for the virtual dispatch mechanism. Or if you have **no** data in the class, in which case the class is still required to take up some space (which in turn is because every object must have a unique address in memory).

Functions are not part of the data layout of the object. They are only a part of the mental concept of the object. The function is translated into code that takes an instance of the object as an additional parameter, and calls to the member function are correspondingly translated to pass the object.

The number of data members doesn't matter. Compare apples to apples; if you have a class with 10 ints in it, then it takes up the same space that 10 ints would.

Allocating things on the stack is effectively free, no matter what they are. The compiler adds up the size of all the local variables and adjusts the stack pointer all at once to make space for them. Allocating space in memory costs, but the cost will probably depend more on the number of allocations than the amount of space allocated.

Comment: Mental state costs. Constructor being invoked requires function call which is not free in terms of CPU cycles. You've mentioned functions, but I think you should explain constructor part separately as constructor is present in the question and is not inlined.

Comment: @Basilevs what makes you think a constructor call won't be inlined anywhere an ordinary function call couldn't be? Further, depending on the POD status of the class, the default construction might not actually zero-initialize everything anyway. I can never remember the exact rules for that, though, because I have bigger optimizations to worry about approximately 100% of the time. Also, if using classes causes real "mental state" overhead for you, C++ might not be the language for you, nor anything more advanced than C really. Although I really don't understand how anyone can think that way.

Comment: Only function implemented in header can be inlined. There is no inline implementation in the question. Constructor might be implemented in a separate compilation module. Construction action does not matter at all, my point is that constructor call itself costs. Mental state cost can be avoided by using inline functions. It also important to remember that optimizations like this only make sense in heavy load applications.

Answer (score 10):

well, lets just test it all out.  I can compile, with full optimizations, a more complete example like so:

```
void use(int &);

class classWithInt
{
public:
    classWithInt() : someInt(){}
    int someInt;
};
class podWithInt
{
public:
    int someInt;
};

int main() {
  int foo;
  classWithInt bar;
  podWithInt baz;

  use(foo);
  use(bar.someInt);
  use(baz.someInt);

  return 5;

}
```

And this is the output I get from [gcc-llvm](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi)

```
; ModuleID = '/tmp/webcompile/_21792_0.bc'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64"
target triple = "x86_64-linux-gnu"

%struct.classWithInt = type { i32 }

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %foo = alloca i32, align 4                      ; <i32*> [#uses=1]
  %bar = alloca %struct.classWithInt, align 8     ; <%struct.classWithInt*> [#uses=1]
  %baz = alloca %struct.classWithInt, align 8     ; <%struct.classWithInt*> [#uses=1]
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.classWithInt* %bar, i64 0, i32 0 ; <i32*> [#uses=2]
  store i32 0, i32* %0, align 8
  call void @_Z3useRi(i32* %foo)
  call void @_Z3useRi(i32* %0)
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.classWithInt* %baz, i64 0, i32 0 ; <i32*> [#uses=1]
  call void @_Z3useRi(i32* %1)
  ret i32 5
}

declare void @_Z3useRi(i32*)
```

There are some differences in each case.  In the simplest case, the [POD type](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/fpcltf/Pkg/ISOcxx/doc/POD.html) differs from the plain int in only one way, it requires a different alignment, it's 8 byte aligned instead of just 4 byte.

The other noticeable thing is that the POD and bare int do not get initialized.  Their storage is used right as is in from the wilderness of the stack.  The non-pod type, which has a non-trivial constructor, causes a zero to be stored before the instance can be used for anything else.